# regex - multiple matches after a specific word

Tags: regex, pcre

Simplified example: consider the string `aabaabaabaabaacbaabaabaabaa`

I want to match all `aa` occurrences *only* after the `c` in the middle, using one regex expression.

The closest I've come to is `c.*\Kaa` but it only matches the last `aa`, and only the first `aa` with the ungreedy flag.

I'm using the regex101 website for testing.

Comment: What do you think about splitting your string on `c` and using Regex on the last index

Comment: dependent on the language, you may find it's easier and more efficient/obvious to find the first instance of `c` and then get results after it

Comment: @maksymiuk this also works, of course, but I wanted to find a way to do it in one expression, just for the fun of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:\G(?!^)|c).*?\Kaa
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/drUHTv/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|c)` - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) a `c` char
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\K` - forget the text matched so far
- `aa` - an `aa` string.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I supposed that I had to use `\G` somehow, but couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 1):

If it is known that the string contains exactly one `'c'` just match

```
aa(?!.*c)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLLCkP/1)

`(?!.*c)` is a *negative lookahead* that asserts that `'c'` does not appear later in the string.

---

If it is not known whether the string contains zero, one or more than one `'c'`, and `'aa'` is to be matched if and only if the string contains at least one `'c'` and `'aa'` is not followed later in the string by a `'c'`, one can match the regular expression

```
^.*c\K|(?!^)aa
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/8ttKEH/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^      # match the beginning of the string
.*     # match zero or more chars, as many as possible
c      # match 'c'
\K     # reset match pointer in string and discard all previously
       # matched characters
|      # or
(?!^)  # negative lookahead asserts current string position is not
       # at the beginning of the string
aa     # match 'aa'
```

Note that is the string contains no `'c'` there will be no match.

Comment: The problem with this approach is if `c` is not present in the string, it will match all the `aa` characters, which may not be desired. See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLLCkP/2)

Comment: @Ber'Zophus, due to the wording of the question I had assumed it was known that the string contained a `'c'`. You certainly have a point, but if we allow the possibility that the string does not contain a `'c'` we must also allow the possibility that it contains more than one `'c'`. I have modified my answer to address your point.